# HTML, CSS, Javascript creating circles inside eachother

Tags: javascript, html, css, geometry

I need to make circles inside each other with HTML, CSS and Javascript, with the possibilty of clicking on a button, which will automatically add another circle to it. The newly added circle will be the most outer one.

Any ideas of how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the circles, you need to set border-radius to a value big enough (usually, more than half of the biggest of width and height).

To add a bigger circle, you need to copy the previous circles, create another, bigger, one, and paste the copied circles inside it. This is a jQuery snippet, but you can use any framework, or even plain js:

```
var $container = $('#container'),
    $previous_circles = $container.html()

$container
  .html('<div class="circle bigger_circle"></div>')
  .find('.bigger_circle')
  .append($previous_circles)
  .end()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how should I do it with the css then? The circle bigger_circle should be already defined? I think I would need to keep track of how many circles are already shown somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you define all possible circles in your css, or create relative sizes. ie: .circle { display:block; width:100%; height:100%; border-radius:50%; padding:20px } - the padding will ensure that the inner circles are smaller. Make sure the container has width and height.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention position:absolute. Here's the styling: #container { width:500px; height:500px; margin:0 auto; position:relative; } .circle { border-radius:50%; border:1px solid #000; position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; right: 10px; bottom: 10px; }